# Best setting for HTTPJVMMaxHeapSize in Domino 8.5.3 64 Bit

Tags: memory, jvm, xpages

I am trying to find a definitive answer as to what the best setting is for the JVM Heap Size in Domino 8.5.3 FP4 - 64 Bit for Windows.

I know that by default it's set to 1024M. Some web sites have suggested that it's recommended to be 1G / 1024M - but that's the default setting so it that as good as it gets?

Other sites have said 25% of available RAM.

My Domino server has 12GB RAM available. It's currently got HTTPJVMMaxHeapSize = 1024M and Task Manager tells me that around 7GB of RAM is in use and nhttp.exe is using around 1.1GB. I want to increase this Heap to 2GB or 3GB if possible - will there be any issues doing to?

I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition.

Comment: Is there some reasoning why you WANT it? You can start with googling generic advices from Java world, but keep in mind, Domino is different. You can start with analyzing GC (JavaVerboseGC=1, than pass console logs to ISA) and then decide whether you NEED bigger heap.

Comment: Of course there's a reason why I want it - I want to make sure that with 12GB of RAM, Domino is configured as best it can be to make use of that memory. But knowing Domino, there's bound to be a plateau where if you go above it, random things start to happen. This server will be processing requests from several hundred concurrent users so it needs to be able to handle that many sessions adequately.

Comment: Look for that GC. It will give you clues that fit to your setup.

Comment: On my blog / demo server, which is running 64 bit Ubuntu, I have the heap max set to 3GB, and it runs beautifully. But 3GB seems to be the max it allows, at least in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

Speaking from an XPages perspective:

## 1 - Understand the dynamics of the working set and hardware

That is, understand what the application code, server runtime, and hardware profile is doing when processing a given working set (ie: the XPages application(s) within the server).  Is the application coded in a non-optimal manner in terms of lifecycle execution and memory usage?  Is the application making use of memory or disk persistence for component tree serialization?  Is the server assigned an adequate amount of JVM memory?  Is the hardware providing enough CPU and memory?

## 2 - Profile and monitor the working set with upper limit loads

To fully answer some of the questions in #1, detailed performance and scalability profiling must be carried out using tools like the XPages Toolbox and Eclipse Memory Analyzer.  Furthermore, test the working set using Rational Performance Tester (or some other performance testing tool) to mimic real life concurrent workloads in a test environment.  This allows you to set up a test environment where you can hit your application with (n) number of concurrent users using automation and collect that all invaluable data on health etc.

## 3 - Analyse the profile information to identify bottlenecks within the working set

Remember your working set can be one or more applications.  Each doing something different, and having different load requirements.  Be specific about the task at hand - do you want to tune the system more generally for all applications (for an average scale) or do you want the server to be fully optimized for a specific application (for a targeted scale)?

## 4 - Optimize the working set where applicable

Get in and make changes to the XSP / Java / ServerSide JavaScript code where applicable - use your knowledge of the XPages Request Processing Lifecycle and also look out for those hungry JVM memory consumers under high end load scenarios.  Always favor disk persistence (disk storage is cheaper than RAM!) and code your custom Java objects and Managed Beans accordingly to cope with serialization and restoration.  And make the trade-offs between function and speed in these scenario's where high scalability ends up burning CPU... a smarter UX with targetted functions / actions etc.

## 5 - Scale the hardware where applicable

Be prepared to increase cores, clock speeds, RAM, disk storage based on the needs of the working set - a cyclic approach to profiling, monitoring, and optimizing the working set will shed more and more light on the suitability of the hardware as this process evolves.

## 5 - Repeat from #2 until the working set and hardware performs and scales to the expected requirements / load expectancy of the system

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to set server's notes.ini param `JavaVerboseGC=1` with console output into console.log in IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT directory. After some time, take that log file and use [IBM Support Assistant](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/isa/workbench.html) with tool [IBM Monitoring and Diagnostic Tools for Java - Garbage Collection and Memory Visualizer (GCMV)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27013116#IBM%20Monitoring%20and%20Diagnostic).

This could help how to interpret collected data: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27013824&aid=1.

You definitely should do that if you get OutOfMemoryException.

Heap size set too high can lead to fewer GC runs but taking longer time - server will periodically "hang" for very short time. So too high setting is not recommended.